# Apache Ignite grid gets auto activated when persistence is disabled

Tags: ignite, gridgain, apacheignite

We are having an Apache Ignite grid where we have persistence enabled but we are facing issues with persistence as we often face grid getting hung due locking while checkpointing.

We now want to move to non persistence grid but the problem is that non-persistent grid is auto active from start itself which we dont want. If grid is auto enabled then it doesn't give us time to do some initial checks before starting processing of tasks.

Is there any way to achieve this either in form of some initial delay or starting grid in inactive form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the desired behaviour is totally achievable.
You can specify it as a part of your `IgniteConfiguration`, here is the right [property](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setClusterStateOnStart-org.apache.ignite.cluster.ClusterState-). Possible options are:

- `ClusterState.INACTIVE`
- `ClusterState.ACTIVE`
- `ClusterState.ACTIVE_READ_ONLY`

Please note, this property should be strictly consistent across a cluster.